# error (13: Permission denied) in nginx 1.4.1

Tags: permissions, php, nginx

I am facing this issue on my nginx setup on ubuntu 13.10 
I got these weird error on the log of my local domain

```
2014/04/06 21:29:37 [crit] 18065#0: *3 stat() "/media/user/Backup/Sites/sp/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: sp.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "sp.local"
2014/04/06 21:29:37 [crit] 18065#0: *3 stat() "/media/user/Backup/Sites/sp/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: sp.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "sp.local"
2014/04/06 21:29:37 [crit] 18065#0: *3 stat() "/media/user/Backup/Sites/sp/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: sp.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "sp.local"
```

this configuration was working before upgrading to this version 13.10

the permissions on this folder is : 755 & there is no log recorded on php fpm error log

I had did every idea to fix it with no luck 
could you please suggest / help me , It would be appreciated
Thanks

*update:*

- I am not using SElinux
- the files are located in non encrypted drive
- nginx is installed on encrypted drive  `/` , is this the issue ??

Relevant mount point:

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/tawfek/Backup type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

ls -l output :

```
total 712
drwsr-xr-x  6 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:26 app
drwsr-xr-x  8 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:26 downloader
drwsr-xr-x  3 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 errors
drwsr-xr-x  2 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:26 includes
drwsr-xr-x 15 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 js
drwsr-xr-x 13 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 lib
drwsr-xr-x 13 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:26 media
drwsr-xr-x  3 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 nbproject
drwsr-xr-x  2 tawfek tawfek   4096 Mar  8 13:10 pear
drwsr-xr-x  2 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 pkginfo
drwsr-xr-x  2 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 shell
drwsr-xr-x  5 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 skin
drwsr-xr-x 11 tawfek tawfek   4096 Apr  6 21:25 var
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   2834 Feb  1 11:39 api.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   2831 Feb  1 11:39 cron.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek    716 Mar 24 22:38 cron.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   1150 Feb  1 11:39 favicon.ico
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   5979 Feb  1 11:39 get.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   2673 Apr  6 22:17 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   2366 Feb  1 11:39 index.php.sample
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   6441 Feb  1 11:39 install.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek  10421 Feb  1 11:39 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek  10679 Feb  1 11:39 LICENSE.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek  10410 Feb  1 11:39 LICENSE.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek   1319 Feb  1 11:39 mage
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek    886 Feb  1 11:39 php.ini.sample
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek    478 Feb 17 19:08 php.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 tawfek tawfek 585086 Feb  1 11:39 RELEASE_NOTES.txt
```

Comment: perhaps, You are using selinux?

Comment: What effect it has on site? Also, please add output of `ls -l /media/user/Backup/Sites/sp/`.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo mount`?

Comment: @Braiam I just updated the question with info from [this chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13856/room-for-danatela-and-tawfekov).

Comment: And from which user do you start nginx?

Comment: nginx uses the default user = "www-data"

Comment: why you have installed it in / ?, it want to be in /opt/nginx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching with no luck , I backed up my data ,  removed the encryption from the drive and restore my data , every thing worked as expected

please note that `encryptfs` was the issue , I can't give detailed / technical explanation 
but that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my solution will work, just give it a try.

Probably, your nginx version is outdated.

```
# apt-cache policy nginx
nginx:
  Installed: 1.4.1-3ubuntu1.3
  Candidate: 1.5.12-1+saucy0
  Version table:
     1.5.12-1+saucy0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/development/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.4.1-3ubuntu1.3 0
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.1-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

To install the latest version, you need to add [Nginx's team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/development)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/development
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it will not work, the problem will be resolved in next Ubuntu release (14.04), which will come soon (April, 17th).

May be Nginx expects owner of `/media/user/Backup/Sites/sp/` to be `www-data`. To change:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/user/Backup/Sites/sp/
```

If the one of those solutions work, please reply which.

Answer (score 0):

在 Ubuntu 14.04 裡，若將 nginx 的 root (Apache`s DocumentRoot) 指到 **/media/USERNAME/** 底下也會發生此問題，所以最後在下改掛載其它路徑以避開此問題。

If we nginx`s root (like DocomentRoot of Apache) is setting to under the **/media/USERNAME** on Ubuntu 14.04, we will has the some problem, so My solutiom is mount other path to workaround.

---

## My environment

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2

$ ls -l /media/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  19 jonny jonny 4096 Sep 25 18:17 data
drwxr-xr--+  3 jonny jonny 4096 Sep 23 17:01 jonny
```